# Serverside method throws error on method call, but not on client

Tags: meteor

On my client I have the following code

```
# If clicking on unit while target is set, activates action
  'click .actor': () ->
    character = Meteor.user().character()
    target = Session.get('target')
    skill = Session.get('selectedSkill')

    if target and skill
      console.log character.battle()
      Meteor.call('useSkill', skill, character, target, (err) ->
        if err then console.log err.reason
      )
```

Here, when I invoke the `character.battle()`, it correctly returns the battle document. But when I call the same method, on the same object, in the `useSkill()` method, it throws the following error

```
Exception while invoking method 'useSkill' TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'battle'
```

Serverside method

```
useSkill: (skill, actor, target) ->
    cost = skill.cost

    console.log "battle: #{actor.battle()}"
    ....
```

and the association '`battle()`' method

```
@Characters = new Meteor.Collection('characters', 
    transform: (entry) ->

        entry.battle = () ->
            Battles.findOne({active: true, $or: [{characterOneId: this._id}, {characterTwoId: this._id}]})

        return entry
)
```

Comment: Are you declaring `Characters` collection on `server` and `client` ?

Comment: I'm declaring it in a lib folder, so it should be available on both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only pass serializable objects as method arguments. In other words, all the custom methods you added on the client side are not preserved when you pass the `actor` argument like that. To have access to your custom function on the server, you need to create the object on the server.

So instead of passing the whole `character` object, just pass its `_id` and find it again inside the method:

```
useSkill: (skill, actorId, target) ->
  actor = Characters.findOne actorId
  ...
  console.log "battle: #{actor.battle()}"
```

Comment: This is a better method anyway as it saves you bandwidth.

Comment: Should one never pass anything but _id's to meteor server method calls?

Comment: Well, you usually shouldn't pass the whole database item you could fetch on the server – in such cases it's better to pass the `_id`. Often you'll pass other things, though, like a whole object you want to insert (so it's not in the db yet).

Comment: Plus: you can never pass a function.

Comment: Problem is I have to different collections: Characters and Souls, which are mostly identical and I tried to implement polymorphism by adding a transform method 'collection' that returns the collection so I can call something like eval(actor.collection).find.., but that's not possible when I only send the ID

Comment: The simplest solution I can think of is to pass the item type as well. So add `type` as your method parameter, pass `character.collection()._name`, and on the server fetch the right collection based on its name.

Comment: that approach just seem awfully hacky to me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61051/discussion-between-tarlen-and-hubert-og).

Answer (score 0):

Functions are not serialized by EJSON and NOT send over DDP.
In `Meteor.call` pass id of character:

```
Meteor.call('useSkill', skill, character._id, target, (err) ->
   if err then console.log err.reason
)
```

In `useSkill` method find actor  :

```
useSkill: (skill, actorId, target) ->
    cost = skill.cost
    actor = Characters.findOne actorId
    console.log "battle: #{actor.battle()}"
```